# PYTHON (Jython) how to get DATE TIME value in string - all before specific string?

Tags: python, date, jython

I have string which contains timestamp:

```
Wed Apr 24 14:39:49 CEST 2013
```

Of course I have this similar values in many records so I want to get all before `CEST`. (I have records and with CEST 2012, 2013,2014...), and year after CEST. Also I want to delete Day information.

On example I want results:

```
2013 Apr 24 14:39:49 
2013 Apr 26 14:39:49
```

What methods should I use?

Thank you

Comment: You know what that `CEST` stands for and that it doesn't stay there the whole year long?

Comment: but you are right I need inforamtion about year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from dateutil import parser
dt = parser.parse('Wed Apr 24 14:39:49 CEST 2013')
```

`dt` is a datetime object you can use/format any way you want. For example:

```
dt.strftime('%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S')
# returns '2013 Apr 24 14:39:49'
```

Comment: sorry can I have this result:2013 Apr 24 14:39:49

Comment: I want to exclude CEST and day (WED) and put 2013 on the first place. thank you.

Comment: what is synonym for SUBSTRING methodn in Java for PYTHON? without need for some importing

Comment: I can not import this class so I will try on longer way. I can use on example STR function but can not find which is synonym for SUBSTRING method thank you